# How to upload a file to server on objective C?

Tags: objective-c, file-upload

I want to ask a question about the objective C. I have create a .csv file and I want to upload to a server. However, I have no idea on how to do it. Can anyone provide any example or library for me to do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have an easier time doing this with [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), specifically, take a look at [this sample code](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) that shows how to upload a file.

Then, for actually initiating the request, take a look at [creating an asynchronous request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_an_asynchronous_request).

Comment: @Blaenk, thank you for your help. But I am not going to use the ASIHTTPRequest, does there is any other for the objective C provide?

Comment: Just in case you're confused, ASIHTTPRequest is Objective-C: you can use it for any Mac or iPhone project.

Comment: @Blaenk, thank you for your reply. Due to some reasons, I cannot use it. Therefore, would you provide another suggestions for me? thank you.

Comment: You can probably use NSMutableRequest and NSMutableData to construct the POST data. Take a look at this page: http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload